# infopath 2010: rules and repeating table

Tags: infopath, infopath2010, infopath-2007

I have a repeating table with 6 columns.
Column 5 needs to be entered by the user with two numbers like "1234567890 / 1234".
The first ten digits in this field, the first number, is to be looked up in the database and retrieve an email address matched with this number.
The email address is then to be put in the textbox of column 6.
My first attempt was a rule on the textbox in column 5, when it changes look up the email address, but that worked only for the first line.
My second attempt was a button on the form to perform the ruling, but I get the same result.
The formula is:
 
`@Email[starts-with(@CostCenterID; substring(txtCostCenterGLacc; 1; 10))]`

So this looks in the email field of a database table where the field "CostCenterID" starts with the first 10 digits in the repeating table field "txtCostCenterGLacc".
How can I make this work on all the lines in the repeating table?Either by clicking a button or (preferred) by rule on field in column 5 in the repeating table.
I hope someone can help.
rg. Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft stated the way the repeating table with rules works as it should be.

The solution is to use the code behind to accomplish this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implementing the rule on column 5, try putting code as the default value in column 6 (drawing from column 5) and leave the refresh this value upon calculation field checked. I think you might need to add a little more detail to this question to get it answered.   Its unclear whether nothing is showing up in field 6 or the same value is appearing in field 6.

Comment: I have tried that too, but then it also doesn't work.
With the rule on column 5, only the first row gets a value in the last column. The other rows stay empty.
If I put the code as a value on column 6, they all get the same value based on the first row.

Comment: Have you manually created all the rows or are you trying to do this dynamically?  Dyamic population from a data connnection is not possible OOTB in 2010.  You will need Qrules to do that or you can do it yourself programatically.

Comment: You are going to have to create rules for every row of the repeating table then.  Sounds like you may only have a rule set up for the first row of the table.  You will need to set up a rule for each manually created row and select the appropriate fields per row to get the proper population you are describing.  Are you doing this already?

Comment: It should create a new group in your fields list for each new row you create.

Comment: Via our IT I asked Microsoft for help. If I get the solution, I'll post it here.